# Model evaluation with cosine similarity TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'rv_continuous_frozen' and 'rv_continuous_frozen'

Tags: python, python-pdfreader

For my model evaluation, I am using cosine similarity with below code:

```
cosine_similarity = (np.dot(np.array(v1), np.array(v2))) / (norm(np.array(v1)) * norm(np.array(v2)))
```

But getting below error, any help here

```
<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_continuous_frozen object at 0x000001E703C665A0>
<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_continuous_frozen object at 0x000001E701D1EEA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\91888\OneDrive\Desktop\SkillMatch\Doc2Vec_Test_Resume.py", line 102, in <module>
    print((norm(np.array(v1)) * norm(np.array(v2))))
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'rv_continuous_frozen' and 'rv_continuous_frozen'
```

For my model evaluation, I am using cosine similarity

Comment: Please share your full code.